# Erro de NULL ao adicionar uma nova linha

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Bom galera, tenho uma banco como descrito na imagem abaixo:

[image: Tabelas]

Tenho algumas questões:

```
A) Uma geladeira da marca Brastemp 220 V que custa R$ 700.
B) Três cadeiras de madeira em cores diferentes, cada uma custando R$ 53,40.
```

Resposta: `INSERT INTO Produtos (descricao,marca,preco) VALUES ('Geladeira','BrasTemp',700)
INSERT INTO Eletrodomesticos(voltagem) VALUES (220)`

Mas esta aparecendo este erro na questão A:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 8
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Tipo', table 'LOJAMIX.dbo.Produtos'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>   Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CodBarra', table 'LOJAMIX.dbo.Eletrodomesticos'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Como que resolvo esses erros?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Como as as colunas descritas não podem ser nulas e não possuem um valor *default*, você tem que inserir alguma coisa. Assim:

```
INSERT INTO Produtos (descricao, marca, preco, Tipo) VALUES ('Geladeira', 'BrasTemp', 700, 'Eletro')
INSERT INTO Eletrodomesticos (voltagem, CodBarra) VALUES (220, '')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/WithNull.sql).

Comment: ahhh funcionou. Mas se nao pode ser NULO quando insiro essas aspas simples ''  o banco subentende que passei algum valor? é isso

Comment: Exatamente. É um texto sem nada, mas não é nulo. Não quer dizer que é o certo a fazer na aplicação, mas é o jeito de funcionar. O ideal é colocar um valor que signifique algo. Se não pode ser nulo, tem um motivo, colocar nada é quase trapacear.

Comment: Poxaa, Mas para essa questão tenho que trapacear para inserir ? isso nao afeta a segurança do banco será que existe uma forma de resolver sem trapacear ?

Comment: A segurança não. Aí tem que ver só se pode ficar sem nada ou não, é uma questão de dados. Você pode simular alguma coisa, para não ficar "em branco".

Comment: Valeu bigown, sou iniciante em banco de dados, obrigado pelo esclarecimentos :D

Comment: bigown  se possivel queria tirar só mais uma duvida, na tabela Moveis e Eletrodomesticos existem chaves estrangeiras [Fk] da propria tabela, porque se uma chave estrangeira faz referencia a outra tabela ? ou seja ela deveria ser estrangeira em outra tabela e nao na propria tabela.

Comment: Este diagrama não deixa muito claro, mas é estrangeira em relação a outra tabela mesmo. Ainda que seja possível ter uma chave estrangeira na mesma tabela, raro, mas é.

Comment: Dê uma lida nisto que eu acho que você ainda não conhece bem o site: [tour]